# Facebook sharebutton problem <title=> attribute

Tags: facebook, attributes, dynamic, share

I'm having a bet of a problem, in my site I use the following line to share on facebook, 
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={$my_base_url}{$story_url}&t={$title_short}

the problem is that story_url variable is replaced with the following story?title=plah_plah
as that my site pages are dynamically generated and they need that variable in order to fetch the correct page
and that causes facebook to place the content of the story - that it posts in the description - into the title.

is there is a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create the facebook button in a javascript, and use window.title to set what that title would be.

The simplest way to do this would be to have a tag like this

```
<script>
    document.Write('http://wwwfacebook.com?sharer.php?u=' + window.location + '&t=' window.title);
</script>
```

Adding one more example.  This seems to add a full link with a share icon.

```
<script>
    u = encodeURIComponent(location.href);
    t = encodeURIComponent(document.title);
    document.write('<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=' + u + '&t=' + t + '">Share on Facebook <img src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif" /></a>');   
</script>
```

Whenever it's encountered, it will add whatever is in Document.Write to the document, and you can use the built-in location (URL) and title properties to make things right.

Hope this helps,

Comment: unfortunately i would like to keep it simple to avoid conflicts and site load problems. plus i don't know how to do that actually

Comment: I used the following code and for some reason it just gives me blank page:
<a href="javascript:Faceb()" onClick="javascript:Faceb();return false;"> <img src="{$my_base_url}{$my_pligg_base}/modules/social_bookmark/images/facebook.gif" border="0" alt="submit to facebook" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Faceb()
{
    document.write('<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=' + window.location + '&t={$title_short}">');   
}
</script>

Comment: the problem still exists since at the end the title= parameter is passed to share.php, is there is a way to over come this?